# Finding the position of repeated values in a logical array

Tags: find

If I have a vector such as:

0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0

How do I find the position of the first time there are two consecutive 1s. I.e. the answer to the above would be 9.

Thanks!

Comment: If there was even an attempt to solving the problem I'd weigh in a mostly complete solution.

Comment: Sorry if the question was lacking detail... in previous questions when i've specified what I'd tried, I was advised not to due to the XY problem

Comment: I've had a play around with my code, and this works:

Comment: `function output = find_onset(data)


output = zeros(length(data),1);

for j = 1:length(data);

    if data(j,1) == 1 && data(j+1,1) == 1 && data(j+2,1) == 1

output(j,:) = 1;

    else

        output(j,:) = 0;

    end

  end

 output = find(output);

    output = output(1,1);

`

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment, so will give you a hint here: "Finite State Machines"

Comment: I agree this is the best way to think of the problem. Here is a full solution to OP's question http://imgur.com/LfYfl2K